# Плавный скролл страницы, но не к якорю

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой малой информации по плавной прокрутке страницы на js.
Может у Вас есть библиотеки или заготовки на подобии -https://greensock.com/scrollsmoother/
И возможно ли подключить gsap-scrollsmoother или только нужно делать покупку на год?

Comment: Чем scroll-behavior: smooth не устраивает? И как это не по якорю? Мышкой скролл итак плавный

Comment: Привет, Denis! Смысл в том чтобы только при скролле был эффект плавной прокрутки страницы, но не при событие клика. Информации плавно прокрутки до якоря достаточно... scroll-behavior: smooth - работает при событие клика на силку

Comment: Не совсем могу понять, можете привести пример?

Comment: gsap в этом случае только платно, бесплатно locomotive scroll

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае это скорей всего - ScrollMagic / butter.js. Но можно посмотреть и на такие варианты: Smooth Scroll, One Page Scroll